How do I use an if statement to reference a selection of a list of strings?
I am trying to use an if statement to:

If the user selects a certain day of the week
Then fill an array list with the chores for that day

Currently my if statement doesn't seem to be referencing what day is of the week is selected and instead just outputs the "else" for the length of the list.
Is there a better way to go about this?
p.s. I'm a java novice so I apologize if the wording of the question is weird :) Thanks!
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class DayChooser{

    void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Daily Chore Chart");
    
        List<String> days = List.of("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" );
        JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(days.toArray(new String[0]));
        JList<String> chores = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<>());
    
        box.addActionListener( evt->{
           DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)chores.getModel();
           model.clear();
    
           model.addElement(box.getSelectedItem() + " Chores");
           for(int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) { 
            if (days.equals("Monday")) {
                model.addElement("1. Clean the Bathroom");
                model.addElement("2. Do the Laundry");
                model.addElement("Do it");
           }
            else 
                model.addElement("No Chores!");
                
           }
        });
        
        DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)chores.getModel();
        model.addElement("Daily Chores");
        model.addElement("1. Make the Bed");
        model.addElement("2. Clean the Litterbox");
        model.addElement("3. Wash the Dishes");
        model.addElement("4. Wipe down the Counters");
    
        frame.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(chores, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
       DayChooser dc = new DayChooser();
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( dc::buildGui );
    
    }

}


if (days.equals("Monday")) { this can never be true, since days is a List of Strings, not a String. Did you mean if ( days.contains("Monday")) ? or perhaps (String)box.getSelectedItem().equals("Monday") -> something like that

in the line above your for loop you used box.getSelectedItem() to get the currently selected item. You should perform your checks against this item, and probably save this in a variable so that it can be reused. Also, i m not too sure what you are trying to do with the for loop. You mentioned you want to fill the chores of the selected date, so a for loop is not necessary when you can access the selected day (via the variable mentioned previously)

@Stultuske Thank you! I ended up using if (box.getSelectedItem().equals("Monday")) and it worked great. I could've sworn I had tried something similar, but I must've had the syntax wrong. Thanks!

@BIBOOunit I'm not sure what I was trying to do with the for loop either... lol deleted. Thank you!

@abbey I'll put it in an answer, that way you can set the question to "resolved".

Your issue lies in this line:
if (days.equals("Monday")) {

days is a List of Strings, so it will never be equal to one single String, not even if that String is the only String in the List.
What you need to do, is the same as you already did earlier, get the selected item from your box. Just replace that if statement by the following one:
if ( box.getSelectedItem().equals("Monday")) {

or, to follow some good practices:
if ( "Monday".equals(box.getSelectedItem()) {

Even if something fishy would occur, and box.getSelectedItem() would return null, this would avoid throwing a NullPointerException
